# How to deploy contracts via DAO proposals?

Tags: dao, governance, compound-protocol

Suppose I have a DAO like Compound. What would be the process if I wanted to deploy a contract via a proposal? How will I pass the bytecode and how will it be deployed?

Most of the current proposals I see right now in any governance are just contract interactions, none of them are deploying new contracts.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it's absolutely possible to deploy contracts via DAO proposals**, although it is certainly less common than proposals focused on interacting with existing contracts.  Here's how the process would typically work in a DAO like Compound, along with the reasons why you might not see them as frequently:

1. **Process of Deploying a Contract via a DAO Proposal**

   **Proposal Creation:** A member drafts a detailed proposal outlining:

   **Rationale:** Why this new contract is needed and its benefits.

   **Bytecode:** The compiled bytecode of the new contract.

   **Constructor Arguments:** If the contract needs any input values on deployment.

   **Security Audits:** Proof the code has undergone an audit, if applicable.
2. **Off-Chain Discussion:** Community discussion and scrutiny on forums, as with typical proposals. This is vital due to the
   heightened security implications of deploying new code.
3. **On-Chain Voting:** If off-chain sentiment is positive, the proposal proceeds to an on-chain vote using the DAO's governance
   token (e.g., COMP for Compound).
4. **Execution:** If the proposal passes:

   **Timelock:** Successful proposals often enter a timelock period as a safety measure.

   **Contract Deployment:** A designated address (potentially a multisig controlled by the DAO) executes a transaction that:
   Deploys the contract with the provided bytecode.
   Sends any necessary constructor arguments.

While it's not a built-in mechanism in any DAO Protocol, it's feasible to achieve automated contract deployment following successful proposal acceptance within the Compound Finance system. Here's a potential strategy:

**Leveraging the Timelock Contract**

Compound's **Timelock.sol** contract features the **executeTransaction** method, accepting a **target address** and **call data** as parameters. This method provides an avenue for deployment execution by strategically employing one of the following options:

**1. Dedicated Deployer Contract**

Upon proposal acceptance, the target address within the executeTransaction call could point to a purpose-built 'Deployer' contract.
This contract possesses the sole responsibility of deploying new contracts as instructed by governance outcomes.
The call data would incorporate the necessary bytecode and constructor arguments for the desired contract.

**2. Factory Contract**

Alternatively, the target address could reference a factory-pattern contract designed to instantiate multiple contracts under predefined conditions.
Similarly, the proposal's call data would contain the requisite bytecode and constructor parameters.

Comment: This seems like an AI-generated answer, and it doesn't answer the question of how will the practical look like. How exactly will we pass the bytecode and how the deployment will go through?

Comment: Earlier I tried to assert that it is possible for the automation of deploying a new contract once the proposal is accepted.

We can leverage the Timelock.sol smart contract from Compound Finance where we have executeTransaction method in Timelock.sol where 2 params are target address and call data. 

Here the target address could be:
Dedicated Deployer Contract  OR Factory Contract 

These contract will deploy the bytecode carried by the call data(bytes), once the on-chain or off-chain proposal is accepted by getting majority of votes.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to deploy contracts via proposals. A better and more common approach is to deploy the contract beforehand. This allows for the verification and configuration of the contract, as well as a thorough review of the deployed contract. Subsequently, a proposal can be used to integrate the new contract's address into the protocol.

For instance, if you want to deploy a new Interest Rate Model contract and set it into the cToken, you would first deploy the new contract, verify it, and then create a proposal to update the address in the protocol. Similarly, if you want to update the implementation of a proxy, you would again deploy the new implementation prior to creating the proposal.

This process ensures that all changes are properly reviewed and verified before being integrated, enhancing the security and reliability of the protocol.

---

If for some reason, you must deploy contracts via proposals, you could use the `CreateCall` contract of the Gnosis Safe infra:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x9b35Af71d77eaf8d7e40252370304687390A1A52#code

Call the `performCreate2` of the contract and provide the bytecode.